# How to set up Android kernel development environment for Sony Xperia ZR (and potentially similar ones)

Tags: kernel, android, system-installation

Building on and motivated by [this great guide for installing the Android SDK](https://askubuntu.com/a/318247/181442) on Ubuntu, I would like to collect instructions for installing all necessary tools and sources for compiling (and potentially developing) kernels for the [Sony Xperia ZR phone](http://www.sonymobile.com/global-en/products/phones/xperia-zr/).

Comment: @Braiam: Please read the complete question and answer below. The linked guide is incomplete for the Xperia ZR kernel tree. Why would I otherwise bother to do it all again? And why did you remove the `sony` tag?

Answer (score 3):

**Step 1**

Follow the [Complete Installation Guide for Android SDK on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/318247/181442).

**Step 2**

Install the following packages (I use Synaptic package manager from the Ubuntu Software Repository, but you could do that on the command line via `sudo apt-get install <package>`):

- `git` for downloading the ARM toolchain
- `lzopt` which is required for building the kernel

**Step 3**

Download the [open source archive for the phone from the Sony website](http://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/xperia-open-source-archives/open-source-archive-for-build-10-4-b-0-569-and-10-4-b-0-577/), the direct link is http://dl-developer.sonymobile.com/code/copylefts/10.4.B.0.569.tar.bz2

Extract the archive which contains the three subdirectories `external`, `kernel` and `vendor`, I put them into `~/10.4.B.0.569`.

**Step 4**

Download the pre-built ARM toolchain binaries from the android Git repository using the following command:

```
$ git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-eabi-4.6
```

I did that in my `~/` directory, where a `arm-eabi-4.6` subdirectory was created.

**Step 5**

To configure the build, I basically followed the instructions given in the `~/10.4.B.0.569/kernel/README_Xperia` file. With the directory structures I used, this comes down to the following sequence of commands:

```
$ cd ~/10.4.B.0.569/kernel
$ export ARCH=arm
$ export CROSS_COMPILE=/home/<USER>/arm-eabi-4.6/bin/arm-eabi-
$ make fusion3_dogo_defconfig
```

Note that `fusion3_dogo_defconfig` is for the Xperia ZR and should be replaced if you want to build for a different device (the `~/10.4.B.0.569/kernel/README_Xperia` lists the `Z`, `ZL`, `ZR`, `Tablet Z` and `Tablet Z SGP311/SGP312` variants). Also the `<USER>` needs to be changed to your Ubuntu user name.

**Step 6**
Now we are ready to build the kernel by simply running `make` in the `~/10.4.B.0.569/kernel/` directory. This will take some time and if it worked correctly, should result in a `~/10.4.B.0.569/kernel/arch/arm/boot/zImage` file.

**EDIT:**

Unfortunately, I haven't found a way yet to generate a ramdisk or boot image to run or flash the kernel, so I created [this related question on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21421672/897968) about that.